# P.SE: User is creating bad tags for personal harassment

Tags: support, tags, user-accounts, behavior, spam

Could someone please deny this user from creating bad tags just as personal harassment:

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/1973?tab=activity#tab-top

What would be a more right way to report him rather than creating a question here?

Comment: I'm seeing what can be done.

Comment: Been watching this and looking through the mod tools- apparently there's no easy way to mass-delete a tag.

Comment: @Fishtoaster: Don't mass-delete it, you'll leave the questions with a tag removed as he replaced some in some case... I'm just rolling them back, most of them are corrected already.

Comment: Fair enough- can't mass-delete anyway.  Thank you for rolling back- the user is being addressed.

Comment: [bestestes] and [worstestes] have all been rolled back.

Comment: I'm very sorry to have offended you, I should have left your name off the change reason.

Comment: @Peter No, you shouldn't have done your retagging at all. Besides whatever your issue with Tom is, this constitutes a blatant abuse of the system. *Assuming* you had good intentions (as stated on [meta.prog](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/382/what-is-the-point-with-the-tag-bestestes/383#383)), the least you could have done is gather feedback on your idea *in beforehand* by suggesting this in a meta question.

Comment: I think this should have been asked on meta.programmers.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: @JonSeigel: Perhaps that would've worked out if the site was out of beta, but at the moment there are only 3 Pro Tem moderators of which only 2 are really active. As these 2 moderators can't be there 24/4 and the SOIS has a lot more to handle than our meta I decided to post it here in this case... Thanks anyway, I'll think of that in the future.

Comment: @balpha, sorry about that too.  I'll ask it on meta.prog once I get released from jail.  Problem is, with the exception of maybe one or two guys, meta.prog consists almost solely of people who don't care for my ideas, whereas I seem to get more traction and response on the main site.  The guys who close my questions are the same guys who tell me my questions don't belong there, at least they have the courtesy to do that.

Comment: I think the [Taxonimist badge](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/badges/11/taxonomist?userid=1973) he earned should be removed as well. `[bestestes]`? Really?

Comment: Murphy's Law acted here. I had a power outage. I had time to talk with Fishtoaster and mods of other sites to address this issue properly.

Comment: @Peter: We got a consensus among mods about your immature attitude. We really hope you start to understand that you are participating on a community. Mods and high reps are the representatives to keep the order in house. Majority people doesn't want do the dirty job but they trust on representatives. They prefer the legitimate representatives to do their job and still participating on our community as they can. You can complain but you can't do what you want. We hear your opinions but this is not mean that we agree.

Comment: @Peter:  You can disagree, you can leave (I'm not suggesting it) but you need to follow the rules while you are here. This site was not created to please everybody. I don't like every rule here, but I understand why they exists and I respect them. In democracy everyone has a voice but nobody can do anything you want. Tomorrow I hope to see good contributions by you.

Comment: @bigown, well I'm certainly not going to go on a retag spree again, although I thought that was a perfectly acceptable thing to do (and maybe the number of retags per minute should be addressed) and I certainly won't mention aggrieved person who actually challenged me to do it in the reasons for doing it as a reason for changing the tags.  I hope you'll accept the fact that my intentions were pure and harmless and not meant to offend anyone.

Comment: @Peter: You know what is right now. If you had done it purposely to ruin everything, your suspension would not be for just one day. In fact we discussing the need for any suspension.

Comment: To everyone: Please use Edit Tags for retagging, avoid Edit Question.

Comment: @bigown, most people don't have a separate "Edit Tags" link. I'm assuming what you're talking about is the 10k "inline retag" feature I keep hearing about.

Comment: @TomWij, you can't use multiple @-style replies in one comment. I mean, you obviously _can_, but the notification only fires for the first person listed.

Comment: @Popular: Ok. Anyway, it's a good thing to do when an user can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is just bizarre. To answer you, reporting here on MSO works, you can also e-mail `team@stackexchange.com` or flag any post by that user for mod attention and just explain what's going on.

Comment: Okay, so I've done fine by reporting here... I had the feeling posting it here gets the fastest attention.

Comment: @TomWij Flagging for moderator, or the chat for your site would probably be the fastest.

Comment: See my comment to JonSeigel in the comments to this question, that's why I did it here. And there is no chat yet... :-(

Comment: FWIW [recent feature changes rev 104](http://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/214543/1040) says [meta-tag:profile-page] now has a link ["report this profile"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/yCZ26.png "screen shot"). I tested; link is there and clicking it brings Help Center > Contact (`http://meta.stackexchange.com/contact#option=reportProfile`)

Comment: @gnat to be completely clear, that link really is specifically for reporting the _profile_ itself, not the user to whom the profile belongs. Think "user's avatar is blatant pornography" or "user's about me is racist tirade." Issues with posts and site behaviors should still almost always go through the "classic" flagging system.

Comment: I see, that makes sense