# A user is trying to vandalize posts with abusive speech

Tags: support, suggested-edits, abuse, trolling

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2633473/george-bush) is [repeatedly suggesting edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2633473/george-bush?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) which adds profanity to posts. [This is the latest example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2631345).

Posting here doesn't seem like the right way for me to bring this up; I'm following the accepted answer from [this Meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102018/reporting-users), which states that posting here is as good a way as any to bring this kind of issue to someone's attention:

Comment: the title is a kind of euphemism for that behavior

Comment: What the frag, this is a smear campaign directed at George Bush!

Comment: @OldCheckmark I don't think so, the user started with that name as far as I can remember yesterday and just got angry after his posts were downvoted/deleted/whatever.

Comment: Well, at least we can take solace in the fact that they were all rejected...

Comment: They all stopped for now. Is there some kind of automatic edit ban he/she tripped?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd If they've had nothing *but* rejections, I think the limit is lower. =)

Comment: @J.Steen unless you're willing to sacrifice a sock puppet guess we'll never know! At least no oscillation here... :P

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Now I'm tempted...

Comment: And the user [is now suspended](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2633473/george-bush?tab=activity&sort=suggestion) for three days. Hooray!

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Flag vandalism (you can use the 'other' field to specifically explain what the user is doing), or in the case of vandalism in answers/questions, flag and downvote the post ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61470/209637))
2. Send an e-mail to `team@stackexchange.com` ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66440/209637))
3. Make a meta post here ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/102020/209637))

Considering the business of the mods (see Sha Wiz Dow Ard's comments below), 1. is probably plenty, don't bother with 3. unless it's something frequent, serious, and disruptive.

Comment: I already flagged that user yesterday, flag still waiting. No need to email the team. It's just one troll and not frequent trolling.

Comment: I added where I got the guidance from. If there is a definitive answer, then where is it?

Comment: That was years ago when the sites were still relatively small, these days the team got more than enough work on their hands. That's really not something so crucial that needs a dev intervention.

Comment: Then how about adding that info somewhere? For folks asking, all we have is looking at past meta posts, and if the info is obsolete, it should really be explained and consolidated. That is what meta is for, right?

Comment: There's no definitive answer, each case is specific. If you see a major troll with sock puppet rings then yes it's good idea to email the team to alert the big guys, but otherwise moderators can handle such things by themselves just fine.

Comment: Is there a sort of 'escalation list' for incidents like this? For instance, you said you flagged the user (or I'm guessing his edit(s)) yesterday, but there is still no response. While this is a suggested edit and shouldn't be publicly viewable, it would be nice to have guidelines beyond common sense, since many newer users are unable to judge how busy mods are and how big of an issue the various forms of spam/profanity may be.

Comment: I would _not_ downvote the user's posts as revenge for their edits. That doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that doesn't make sense for a suggested edit in the review queue. Will edit to make sense.

Comment: The user has no posts, I had to flag one of the posts he tried to ruin and of course to explain in the "Other" what's going on. As for escalation, that's what Meta is for. :)